# PHP $_GET['X'] as $X by default

Tags: get, superglobals, register-globals

I have been learning PHP on my own and I've used a web host account to test my scripts, where they have register_globals on by default. I know that this is not secure but I haven't bothered when just testing sample code.

Now I'm working on a small live site for a non-profit organization I'm a member of and the host they are using have register_globals off by default, as it should be.

So, now my question. I have been used to this working (with register_globals on):

**Presume we are loading index.php?pID=1. The code of index.php will contain this row:**

```
if($pID==1) include('content1.php');
```

Note that I've used $pID and not $_GET['pID'] and that I haven't assigned $_GET['pID'] to $pID anywhere in my code. This has worked fine anyway. So (of course) I'm wondering if it's because of register_globals being off that this is suddenly not working when I'm using the same code on my orgs host?

If so, is there a work-around to make superglobals magic again or do I have to live with manually assigning all $_GET variables to my own globals?

Comment: accept that register_globals is in the Top 5 Ultimate Outright Moronically Stupid Design Decisions in PHP, and that its removal and disablement is a **GOOD** thing. Fix your code to work without register_globals, because it's **NEVER** coming back, and you should **NOT** be trying to recreate it.

Comment: What is so bad about manually assigning $_GET variables? You will almost always want to do validation on them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT** attempt to implement `register_globals`, it is a massive security hole and never should have been implemented in the first place. Hence why it was *deprecated* in PHP 5.3 and *removed* in PHP 5.4.

You don't need to re-assign your variables, just replace them with the `$_GET` equivalents. I.E.

```
if($pID==1) include('content1.php');
```

should become

```
if($_GET['pID']==1) include('content1.php');
```

---

To demonstrate why `register_globals` was bad, take a look at this simplified example:

```
if(login_success('admin')) {
  $admin = 1;
}

if($admin == 1) {
  require('super-secret-admin-file.php');
}
```

Because `$admin` is never initialized anywhere, if `register_globals` was on and you opened `file.php?admin=1` you would gain access to the admin section of the site regardless of if you are an admin or not.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use this:
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
  eval("\$".$k." = '".$v."';");
}

Comment: @TorbjörnLokeNornwen **DO NOT USE THAT CODE** This code runs every `$_GET` variable through the `eval()` function which executes any php code inside those variables. I have seen this exact code once before and it resulted in the server being erased when someone put `';system("rm -rf /");` into one of the `$_GET` variables. If you really must emulate that functionality for whatever reason `extract($_REQUEST)` is significantly safer than what  you posted although is still insecure.

Comment: Ok, last solution...
If I assign all $_GET variables (that I know I will use) to my own globals in the index.php and then use them as normal in the included files? Then I wont have to go through all parts of the old code but can still adopt to register_globals being off, right?